# What does the field irq indicate in the kvm_inj_virq event?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, kvm, ftrace

I have generated trace on an intel machine through trace-cmd(ftrace) while running virtual machines through KVM/QEMU hypervisor. In the `kvm_inj_virq` event, the `irq` field is a number indicating the kind of interrupt that's getting inserted. But I need to know the exact meaning of this number like whether it's a network, timer, disk or any other kind of interrupt.

I have attached an image of the trace for reference.
[Sample Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KqCF.png)

I tried searching for the IRQ numbers and their corresponding meaning. I found the first 16 mappings [here](https://www.webopedia.com/reference/irqnumbers/), but I need to know the rest of them.

Comment: Does it match the number in /proc/interrupts?

Comment: _"First 16 mappings"_ are legacy which may not be the case on newest hardware.

Comment: Btw, there is no such function or data type or variable named `kvm_inj_virq` in the (vanilla) Linux kernel.

Comment: @0andriy You're right. I just checked that there's no code for kvm_inj_virq, but then why is there such a tracepoint available to trace in ftrace?